# WinHttpException: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have an ASP.Net Core Wep API Project which does the following tasks:

- Receive request through a controller called ProcessController.
- Take the incoming request and format the data into a string.
- Uses the PostChargeAsync method in the following HttpProcessor class to post the above formatted message on an URL and await for the responnse message to perform further processing.

**Note** that HttpClient is injected using IoC and is a singleton.

```
public class HttpProcessor
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public HttpProcessor(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));            
    }

    public async Task<string> PostChargeAsync(string payload)
    {
        using (var httpRequest = BuildHttpRequest(payload))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    using (var httpContent = httpResponse.Content)
                    {
                        return await httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private HttpRequestMessage BuildHttpRequest(string content)
    {
        return new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://test/process"),
        };
    }
}
```

The **issue** is that when parallel requests (~30 - 50 requests/min) are sent on the ProcessController and the PostChargeAsync method is called I get the following exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
```

I have tried adding the following setting in Web.Config for increasing the maxconnection in connectionManagement:

```
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="100"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
```

but I still get the above mentioned exception.

Any ideas what would have caused the above issue?

Comment: Can you clarify: The code you posted: i.e. PostChargeAsync handling the request? if so, your error is indicating a termination with which server?

Comment: @DaniDev ProcessController is handling the request. The request is formatted and then using PostChargeAsync method to post the formatted request to another third party system using the uri "https://test/process". I have not included the real URI.

Comment: Have you checked if firewall or anti-viruse blocks connection?

Comment: The exception is not continuous but intermittent.

Comment: @nasiroudin I think you are correct in trying to address this through configuration. Just trying to determine whether it should App, IIS or Server? That is why I am trying to understand the source (and meaning) of your error. Can you clarify where this error occurs (in your code?) and the server in question?

Comment: @DaniDev The HttpRequestException occurs here -> [using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest).ConfigureAwait(false)) ] in the code. It is a dotnet core application which is hosted under IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: OK, 0that is what I assumed. Hence it seems to me that the error "An error occurred while sending the request" is not going to be addressed by changing configuration on the system that is running your code but rather with the (Third PartyTarget) since it seems you can't affect changes to that system then possibly try to modify your code so it doesn't try send that request Asynchronistically.

Answer (score 1):

We moved from HttpClient to HttpWebRequest and the issue mentioned above was resolved. There was some issues with HttpClient on .Net Core Runtime 2.0. Note that at the time this post was created, I was using .NET Core SDK 2.1.4 and .NET Core Runtime 2.0.5.